# Creating specialized maps with jQuery and/or Google Maps API

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dictionary

I need to create a range-graded circle proportional map, i.e., a map that has circles overlaying a map the size of which circles indicates the proportional density of what I'm trying to measure.  This is best understood by example, and can be seen here: http://www.d.umn.edu/geog/cartfolder/HTML%20Pages/Map-Types.htm.  I've tried poking around with Google Maps API, and can't find anything that will let me create proportional circles on top of a map display; and, furthermore, I would like to be able to narrow it down by major cities in the U.S. (SF, LA, NYC, Chicago, Dallas, etc.).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
See this examples (in Russian, sorry)
http://mabp.kiev.ua/2010/08/16/custom-maptype-projection-in-google-map-api-v3/
http://mabp.kiev.ua/2010/08/22/google-maps-v3-and-raphael

here is simple sample

```
for (var i=0,j=11;i&ly;j;i++){
        new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeWeight: 2,
            strokeColor : "#ffffff",
            map : map,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            radius : i*1000000
        });
    }
```

http://appdelegateinc.com/samples/Google-Maps-Circle-Overlay/

Comment: Thanks -- this is very helpful.  I'm actually proficient in Russian, so I can make my way through the attached pages (it'll take longer than if they were in English, of course!).